# How to find a optimal value of k to apply k-ary search

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

what algorithm will be used to determine the best value of k to apply k-ary search. e.g. I have array of size 10000 and what should be the size of the sub arrays on which can i apply k-ary search in parallel.

Comment: The array is sorted, right?

Comment: yes, The array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be helpful: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29756/86758

Usually binary search (n=2) will be the fastest.

If you are trying to parallelize search, you won't get any gain by splitting into sub-arrays because you'll throw away the other n-1 sub arrays immediately. If the comparisons are costly, from the linked answer, "-ary search may make a lot of sense in case if comparisons are quite costly and can be parallelized, as then, parallel computers can be applied."

Comment: Yes I understand that. but this que was asked to me in a interview and he later told me a algorithm for it but i forgot the name of algorithm.